# Keyboard hook not restricting key press correctly

Tags: c++, hook, dll-injection

I have a dll that is injected into a specific process with the intention of restricting certain key presses from being sent to the aforementioned process..

This seems to work, with one major flaw.. When the keys are pressed that I intend to restrict, they are still being passed to the process.

I added the line to raise a message box whenever the hook should be returning the value of 1 (restricting the keys from progressing further own the chain), and the message box is raised, and even stranger, the key is stopped from progressing, but whenever I remove the messagebox code the restriction is completely ignored!!

Could anyone highlight what I am doing wrong? Or in the unlikely scenario that it is not my own wrongdoing, but some quirk that I am not aware of, please do let me know.

Many thanks.

Here is my hook proc code, which I expect is where the issue lies.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int KeyboardHook(INT nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    //-- Return unless valid nCode
    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(keyhook_handle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    //-- Setup some bools
    BOOL alt_down = ((lParam & (1U << 29)) == 1);
    BOOL key_last = ((lParam & (1U << 30)) == 0);
    BOOL key_down = ((lParam & (1U << 31)) == 0);
    BOOL let_pass = TRUE;
    //-- Checks for keypresses 
    if (key_last && key_down) {
        if (wParam == VK_F12) let_pass = FALSE;
        if ((wParam == VK_RETURN) && alt_down) let_pass = FALSE;
    }
    //-- If not let_pass then return 1 to restrict key
    if (!let_pass) {
        //MessageBox(NULL, L"Key Stopped", L"Info:", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 1;
    }
    //-- Call the next hook in the chain
    return CallNextHookEx(keyhook_handle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: First, `== 1` should be `!= 0`, so your second test can't work. Then, are you sure the process use window messages for the keyboard ? If it looks like a normal window it probably do, but only you can tell.

Comment: Yes, the process certainly uses messages for the keyboard.  I have tested a low level global hook using within the exe that injects my dll, and everything works as it should from there.. Its only within the dll that it doesn't work properly.